# APL How many integers

Tags: vector, integer, counting, apl

How many integer numbers are in the vector `20.88 10 ¯2.3 0 .555 222 ¯0 2 3.3 9`?

I need to do it using APL.

Please also recommend any links to learn the APL language.

Comment: Welcome to SO Artyr! You'll get more receptive responses if you show us what you've attempted, as this will help us guide you in the correct direction.

Comment: Which APL version do you use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Counting integers

You can check if a number `x` is an integer with `x=⌊x`, but of course APL processes entire arrays at a time, so using the name `v` for your vector, `v=⌊v` gives you a Boolean vector indicating integers (`0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1` in your case) and `+/v=⌊v` is the sum of the Boolean vector, that is the count of integers.

[Try it on *TryAPL*!](https://tryapl.org/?a=v%3D%u230Av%u219020.88%2010%20%AF2.3%200%20.555%20222%20%AF0%202%203.3%209&run)

#### Links to learn APL

For learning APL, [*The APL Orchard*](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52405/the-apl-orchard) is a good place to hang out. There are people there who can help you and an APL chat bot to evaluate small expression. [The chat bot's profile](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/75949/dyalog-apl) has a collection of links to APL resources.

You can also find [transcripts of the *APL Cultivation* lessons](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/52405/the-apl-orchard?tab=conversations) which were held in the APL Orchard.

#### Alternative integer counting method

`1|x` is the division remainder when `x` is divided by one. This gives you the fractional part of `x`. If that fractional part is zero, `x` is an integer: `0=1|x`. Continue as per the above method. [TryAPL!](https://tryapl.org/?a=+/0%3D1%7C20.88%2010%20%AF2.3%200%20.555%20222%20%AF0%202%203.3%209&run)